# Node.Js Retrieve specific data from SQL Server and encode it into JSON Array

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I know this question have many duplicates, but I have already wasted too much time searching for the right solution.

First take a look at my Node.JS:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'myuser',
        password: 'mypass',
        server: 'myip', 
        database: 'mydatabase' 
    };
    sql.close();
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
        var dataqu = '';
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query("select * from AR_Invoices", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err) 
            res.json(recordset);
            sql.close();
        }); 
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000,'0.0.0.0', function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

This code runs fine, but the json result structure is like this :

```
{"recordsets":[[{"Tipe":"Invoices","InvoiceID":411891,"InvoiceNumber":"SR.1701.0001"}]],"recordset":[{"Tipe":"Invoices","InvoiceID":411891,"InvoiceNumber":"SR.1701.0001"}],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[1]}
```

I don't know why but for some reason the result is always resulting in duplicate.

And how to just select `InvoiceID` and `InvoiceNumber` ?

I already tested using `recordset.InvoiceID` or `recordset[0].InvoiceID` but all is always in vain, and the result always in duplicate.

Can anyone explain how to do this properly?

I want the final result became like this :

```
[
   { "InvoiceID":"1", "InvoiceNumber":"mynumber" }
]
```

Comment: Not unexpected. Did you read the [3.x to 4.x changes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#3x-to-4x-changes) documentation? *"Every callback/resolve now returns result object only. This object contains recordsets (array of recordsets), recordset (first recordset from array of recordsets), rowsAffected (array of numbers representig number of affected rows by each insert/update/delete statement) and output (key/value collection of output parameters' values)."*

Comment: i have not see it yet, but is there still workaround so i can get the exactly like my final result above ? or do i need to process just like this ?

Comment: What you've called `recordset` is actually `result` if you use the documentation's terminology. So you'd issue `res.json(recordset.recordset)` to get your desired JSON output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future reference, i finally got how to do this here is my full code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');

app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'myuser',
        password: 'mypassword',
        server: 'myip', 
        database: 'mydb' 
    };
    sql.close();
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err); 
        // create Request object  
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query("select top 2 'Invoices' as Tipe,InvoiceID,InvoiceNumber,InvoiceDate,(select top 1DriverPicture from dbDigitalApp.dbo.tbdriver) as Blob from AR_Invoices", function (err, result) {       


            if (err) console.log(err)  

            var myarr = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < result.recordset.length; ++i) {
                var InvoiceNumber = result.recordset[i].InvoiceNumber;
                var InvoiceDate = dateFormat(result.recordset[i].InvoiceDate, "dd mmmm yyyy");
                var Blob = result.recordset[i].Blob;
                myarr.push({'InvoiceNumber':InvoiceNumber,'InvoiceDate':InvoiceDate,'Blob':Buffer.from(Blob).toString('base64')});

            }   

            res.json(myarr);

            sql.close();
        }); 



    });

});

var server = app.listen(5000,'0.0.0.0', function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

and the result of above code is like this :

[answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOpwE.png)

with above code you can get specific field only and do whatever you want with those specific data, such as change date format or encode base64.
i don't know if this the cleanest way to do this since the node.js has its own function using res.json that can set all field of retrieved data without need to loop through it.

But at least here is my kind of solution, hope it will be helpful to there future people who wondering the same thing like me.